# Unable to access label defined inside loop

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to refer the process to a defined label but i got this error..

> No such label 'IL_A44' within the scope of the goto statement.

My C# code is as :

```
for (i = 0; i < objAttendanceLog.LogRecords.Count; i++)
{
    if (condition1)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < objAttendanceLog.LogRecords.Count - 1; j++)
        {
            if (condition2)
            {
                IL_A44:
                while (j < objAttendanceLog.LogRecords.Count - 1)
                {
                    if (condition3)
                    {
                        j--;
                        break;
                    }
                    j++;
                }
                if (j == objAttendanceLog.LogRecords.Count)
                {
                    j--;
                }
                num3 = data, 
                i = j;
                goto IL_AD8;
            }
        }
        goto IL_A44;
    }
    IL_AD8:;
}
```

Comment: is `IL_A44` your label name , if so you need to access using `IL_A44.Text`

Comment: there is some problem in this case if your second if condition is return false then your c# has no defined `IL_A44` label. because of this you are getting error. you should provide `IL_A44` label outside of the if condition.

Comment: That's because the scope of `IL_A44` is limited to the if block inside your last for loop whereas you are trying to access it from outside of the for loop. Why don't you try explaining what you are trying to do here?

Comment: No need to use labels there, only set j to have a value that doesn't force you to exit the for loop.

Comment: @Webruster OP is talking about C# label here, not asp.net/html one.

Comment: @NikhilVartak in C# we dont call it as `label` , we call it `variable` and if he is stating it as `label` only possible way is that it is a `aspnet` control

Comment: I want 'if(condition2)' not become true in the total execution of for loop, then just execute inner statement of 'if(condition2)' only once...

Comment: https://xkcd.com/292/

Comment: @Webruster ofcourse we call it label. A variable is something, that stores information in memory. A label is a control statement.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt Yes even i am also refering a  Label *as* a control statement that is the reason i mentioned in my  initial comment as `.Text` , i think somehow might missed the flow ..

Comment: @Webruster maybe you misunderstood the question. We are talking about the label, that is the counterpart of the `goto` statement.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt no i guess  i understood it as it suppose to be ,  but plz do enlighten me , sorry for my ignorance .. i'm not arguing just want to make sure that things are right ..

Answer (score 0):

if the two 'condition' are the same things, the following code should do the same thing:

```
int j=0;
for (i = 0; i < objAttendanceLog.LogRecords.Count; i++)
{ 
    if (condition)
    {   
        for (j = i + 1; j < objAttendanceLog.LogRecords.Count - 1; j++)
        {
            if (condition)
            {

                while (j < objAttendanceLog.LogRecords.Count - 1)
                {
                    if (condition)
                    {
                        j--;
                        break;
                    }
                    j++;
                }
                if (j == objAttendanceLog.LogRecords.Count)
                {
                    j--;
                }
                num3 = data, 
                i = j;
                goto IL_AD8;
            }
        }

    }
    else{
         while (j < objAttendanceLog.LogRecords.Count - 1)
                {
                    if (condition)
                    {
                        j--;
                        break;
                    }
                    j++;
                }
                if (j == objAttendanceLog.LogRecords.Count)
                {
                    j--;
                }
                num3 = data, 
                i = j;
                goto IL_AD8;
    }

    IL_AD8:;
}
```

Comment: still, the principle should apply